# How to set base url in Java AWS SDK?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

I am using java aws sdk version `1.11.30` in my project. I need to add support for regions that aren't available in the SDK.

Related to that I found this in my search https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/using-new-regions-and-endpoints/

However, I'm not sure how to do that in Java SDK.

I currently get the s3 instance like below:

```
AmazonS3 s3 = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
       .withRegion(regionName) //regionName is a string for a region not supported by the SDK yet
       .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(new BasicAWSCredentials(aKeyUpload, sKeyUpload)))
        .build()
```

**Question**

How can I set the base url similar to how it is mentioned in the link above?

Comment: Which region(s) aren't supported in that version of the Java SDK? Any reason you cannot upgrade to the latest SDK?

Comment: These regions are in C2S. Upgrading to the latest version of the SDK wouldn't help

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe that this has changed with the very latest (2.x) AWS client, but with 1.11.84 or later, you should be able to do:

```
AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().withEndpointConfiguration(new AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration("endpoint", "region"))
```

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/client/builder/AwsClientBuilder.html

EDIT: Removed deprecated call to `setEndpointConfiguration()`

Comment: Is there a 2.x release? I don't see it on github https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/releases

Comment: Also, the SDK makes use of endpoints.json https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/1.11.30/aws-java-sdk-core/src/main/resources/com/amazonaws/partitions/endpoints.json However, in my applications WAR file I don't see any endpoints.json. Do you know what it is used for and whether I need to add it to my project ..or will doing `setEndpointConfiguration` suffice?

Comment: I get the error "Client is immutable when created with the builder". Seems you cannot set endpoint after build() has been called

Comment: Looks like this was changed: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#11184-2017-01-24

Comment: @DanielScott, sure. Should also note that the change was made beginning 1.11.84. Earlier versions do not have withEndpointConfiguration(). For those older versions, do not use client builder; instead use AmazonS3Client() constructor then .setEndpoint() to set endpoint

Answer (score 0):

When you do this :

```
s3.setEndpoint("https://s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com");
```

It threw `Factory method 'awsRestClient' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Client is immutable when created with the builder`

It's normal because you can't and you must not do change an Object create with Builder

Comment: Looks like this changed in the SDK: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#11184-2017-01-24 - edited my answer to use the new method.

Answer (score 0):

In version 2.x of the SDK things have changed.  See here:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/region-selection.html

In AWS SDK for Java 2.0, all the different region related classes from version 1.x have been collapsed into one Region class. You can use this class for all region-related actions such as retrieving metadata about a region or checking whether a service is available in a region.

example:

```
Ec2Client ec2 = Ec2Client.builder()
                    .region(Region.US_WEST_2)
                    .build();
```

If the region you are attempting to use isn’t one of the constants in the Region class, you can create a new region using the of method. This feature allows you access to new Regions without upgrading the SDK.

```
Region newRegion = Region.of("us-east-42");
Ec2Client ec2 = Ec2Client.builder()
                    .region(newRegion)
                    .build();
```